# python requests.post error when upgrade from 2.7 to 3.6

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, python-requests, http-post, python-3.6

I have this code that is used to send a post to aws api gateway

```
payload = {"thing-name": thing_name, "thing-name-sig": sig}
r = requests.post(api_gw, data=payload)
```

the api gateway returns: 
Method completed with status: 415

which is for unknown media

the problem started when I upgraded python from 2.7 to 3.6

the code was working this this way:

```
payload = {"thing-name": thing_name, "thing-name-sig": sig}
r = requests.post(api_gw, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

which is working normally, but once I upgraded to 3.6 the python compliler started giving me this error:

TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serialable

so I have to change it to `data=payload` to make it pass the python compiler, but then it can not pass the api gateway and it return an known media error of status 415.

so there is two solutions:

1. either some how I find a way to send a JSON string data format in python 3.6 instead of dict JSON serializable object. which I couldn't.
2. some how make the api gateway which an aws service to be able to accept a dict JSON serializable object that is being sent by the python requests.post. which also couldn't do it :(

any help here.

I tried this:

```
payload = {"thing-name": thing_name, "thing-name-sig": sig}
r = requests.post(api_gw, json=payload)
```

it returned this tracback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "emon-device.py", line 154, in <module>
    r = requests.post(api_gw, json=payload)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line                             116, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line                             60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py",                             line 519, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py",                             line 462, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", l                            ine 316, in prepare
    self.prepare_body(data, files, json)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", l                            ine 466, in prepare_body
    body = complexjson.dumps(json)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 180, in default
    o.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: whats the type of thing_name and sig. can please update the type of that. It should be json serializable like string or

Comment: it is string nothing else

Comment: it seems like in python 3 string get convert into bytes so before passing that into payload convert that into string again

Answer (score 1):

The comments I got here were very helpful.. I first I used `str(sig, "utf-8")` for sig variable. then for the whole payload `str(payload)` then after that I faced similar errors in the code migrated from python 2.7 to 3.6 like writing to file requesting bytes not str so I had to add encode() to some string variables like `strBytes.encode()` so that it can be written to a file. thank you very much the code is working fully in python 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
payload = {"thing-name": thing_name, "thing-name-sig": sig}
r = requests.post(api_gw, json=payload)
```

Comment: also gives this error: 'TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable'

Comment: added to the question

Comment: you can convert `thing-name` and `thing-name-sig` to string using `thing_name.decode('utf-8')` and `sig.decode('utf-8')` respectively and try again.

Comment: it says str has no attribute of decode but encode accepted it. but it also saying not serializable